# Filtering All Dropdown to Dropdown using date

Tags: javascript, jquery

The filtering is working but i need to impliment the select all with this two select dropdown.
I need is the two select dropdown have a select all.

HTML:

```
<select name="select1" id="select1">
<option Value="">All</option>
        <option Value="2013-10-10">2013-10-10</option>
        <option Value="2013-10-09">2013-10-09</option>
        <option Value="Onion">Onion</option>
        <option Value="Wewe">Wewe</option>
</select>


<select name="select2" id="select2">
        <option Value="2013-10-10">2013-10-10 Style 1</option>
        <option Value="2013-10-10">2013-10-10 Style 2</option>
        <option Value="2013-10-10">2013-10-10 Style 3</option>
        <option Value="2013-10-09">2013-10-09 Style 1</option>
        <option Value="2013-10-09">2013-10-09 Style 2</option>
        <option Value="2013-10-09">2013-10-09 Style 3</option>
        <option Value="Orange">Orange Style 4</option>
        <option Value="Onion">Onion Style 1</option>
        <option Value="Onion">Onion Style 2</option>
        <option Value="Wewe">wewe Style 2</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#select1").change(function() { 
if($(this).data('options') == undefined){
    /*Taking an array of all options-2 and kind of embedding it on the select1*/
    $(this).data('options',$('#select2 option').clone());
    } 
var id = $(this).val();
var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
$('#select2').html(options);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fRuhn/520/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fRuhn/520/

Comment: Next time just paste the code to the question when the site tells you to, especially when it's just a couple of lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#select1").change(function() { 
    if($(this).data('options') == undefined){
        /*Taking an array of all options-2 and kind of embedding it on the select1*/
        $(this).data('options',$('#select2 option').clone());
    } 
    var id = $(this).val();
    var options = $(this).data('options').filter(function() {
        return  (id === '') || id === $(this).val();
    });
    $('#select2').html(options);
    $('#select2').val($('#select2 option:first').val());
});
```